# how to change metro theme using caliburn.micro

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, microsoft-metro, caliburn.micro

i have built a wpf project with metro and caliburn.micro, i want to change its theme by radiobuttons , like "Dark" and "Light". I have MainWindowViewModel and MainWindowView,
i want to do this theme changing in ViewModel ,not in xaml.cs .

```html
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

```html
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call the method ChangeAppTheme() and pass the theme name.

```
MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.ChangeAppTheme(App.Current, "BaseDark"); // Or "BaseLight"
```

Comment: thanks , how many themes the metro have? where can i find them?